# How to exchange money for asset on Corda?

Tags: corda

I'm trying to write a simple cordapp for issuing and selling bonds.

Got this:

1) Bank issues a bond. (0 inputs, one output, bank the issuer and still the holder)

Want also this:

1) Client can query the bank for the type of bond the client wants to buy (i.e. currency, face value, maturity) and the price of the bond.

If the bank has the bond the client seeks and the client agrees with the price I would like to create a transaction where the bond changes owner from bank to client and where money is exchanged.

Now this transaction should be initiated by the client I'd think. But the client doesn't have the bond state. I can get that from the bank by using sendAndReceive but then the bond state doesn't resolve when translating to ledger transaction (understandably). So I'm thinking do I have to send the whole transaction that issued the bond over to the client first? I guess that would work but seems clunky. Am I missing something?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a question primarily about programming (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: This is a 100% programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the client would need the transaction that issued the bond. Without this, they wouldn't be able to verify this issuance transaction, and therefore couldn't assure themselves that the new transaction they were creating was valid.

It would work as follows:

- The bank would retrieve the bond issuance transaction from their transaction storage and call `SendTransactionFlow` to send this transaction to the client (who would call `ReceiveTransactionFlow` in response)
- The bank would retrieve the bond state from their vault and send it to the client
- The client would build the transaction as normal